# Realizar catch de PSQLException cuando falla la conexión Java-PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, excepciones

no puedo capturar el error de conexión que se da entre Java y PostgreSQL cuando no se realiza una conexión existosa..

Mi código:

```
        package ejercicioT2_01;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.regex.*;
    import org.postgresql.util.PSQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    
    
    public class conectarBDApp  {
    
        public static void main (String [] args) {
            
            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pruebas";
                String usuario = "runsert"; String password = "333";
            
                
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( url, usuario, password);
                
                //Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                String sentenciaSQL = "CREATE TABLE personas2 ( "+ "codigo VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY, "+ "nombre VARCHAR(50), "+ "email VARCHAR(40) "+ ");"; 
                //statement.executeUpdate(sentenciaSQL); con.close(); }
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException ce)
            { System.out.println("PostgreSQL no accesible"); }
            catch (PSQLException ef) { System.out.println("Conexion no realizada");}
            catch(SQLException ex) {System.out.println(ex.getErrorCode());}
        
        }   
        
    }
```

Capturo la excepción pero aun así me aparecen los errores en bruto en la consola, ¿como lo soluciono?

Consola:

```
         nov 16, 2017 5:29:30 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect GRAVE: Connection error:  org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: la
     autentificación password falló para el usuario «runsert» (pgjdbc:
     autodetected server-encoding to be ISO-8859-1, if the message is not
     readable, please check database logs and/or host, port, dbname, user,
     password, pg_hba.conf)
    
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:438)    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)  at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)   at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:450)    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:252)   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at ejercicioT2_01.conectarBDApp.main(conectarBDApp.java:23)

Conexion no realizada
```

Comment: Desde Java 7 puedes capturar todas tus excepciones en un solo bloque: `try { 
  ...
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException |  PSQLException e) { 
  //Manejar diferentes mensajes...
}`

Comment: Gracias A.Cenado pero tu respuesta de todas formas no soluciona el problema.

Comment: Si lo que quieres es imprimir en consola el StackTrace de la excepcion, agrega solo un catch donde esperas `Throwable`, dentro del catch imprimes en consola usando `throwable.PrintStackTrace();`, si mantienes todos esos catchs para darle tratamiento independiente a cada tipo de excepción, en cada uno debes hacer lo último: `exception.PrintStackTrace();`

Comment: ¿Y si le quitas `PSQLException`, no la captura como una `SQLException`?. Según la documentación de la clase, `PSQLException` es dependiente de `SQLException`.

Answer (score 0):

### Después de Java 7

Es posible capturar varias excepciones en un solo bloque `catch`.

Así lo afirma la doc:

> In Java SE 7 and later, a single catch block can handle more than one
>   type of exception. This feature can reduce code duplication and lessen
>   the temptation to catch an overly broad exception.
>
> ---
>
> En Java SE 7 y posterior, un solo bloque catch puede manejar más de un
>   tipo de excepción. Esta característica puede reducir la duplicación de
>   código y disminuir la tentación de atrapar una excepción demasiado
>   amplia.
>
> <sub>Fuente: [Documentación de Java SE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html)</sub>

Entonces, si tienes Java 7+, puedes hacerlo así:

```
    public class conectarBDApp  {

        public static void main (String [] args) {

            try 
            {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pruebas";
                String usuario = "runsert"; String password = "333";


                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( url, usuario, password);

                //Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                String sentenciaSQL = "CREATE TABLE personas2 ( "+ "codigo VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY, "+ "nombre VARCHAR(50), "+ "email VARCHAR(40) "+ ");"; 
                //statement.executeUpdate(sentenciaSQL); con.close(); 

            }catch (ClassNotFoundException | PSQLException | SQLException ex){

                //Mensaje               

            }

    }
```

---

### Antes de Java 7

```
    public class conectarBDApp  {

        public static void main (String [] args) {

            try 
            {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/pruebas";
                String usuario = "runsert"; String password = "333";


                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( url, usuario, password);

                //Statement statement = con.createStatement();
                String sentenciaSQL = "CREATE TABLE personas2 ( "+ "codigo VARCHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY, "+ "nombre VARCHAR(50), "+ "email VARCHAR(40) "+ ");"; 
                //statement.executeUpdate(sentenciaSQL); con.close(); 

            }catch (ClassNotFoundException ce){

                System.out.println("PostgreSQL no accesible"); 

            }catch (PSQLException ef){ 
                System.out.println("Conexion no realizada");

            } catch(SQLException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getErrorCode());
            }

    }
```

### ¿Un extraño caso?

Tu caso es muy extraño. Yo quise reproducir el problema y a mi no me deja poner junto el `catch` de las excepciones `SQLException` y `PSQLException`, porque la última es derivada de la primera como bien indica [la documentación de la clase del JDBC](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/util/PSQLException.html):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo intento esto en mi programa Java:

```
    }catch(SQLException | PSQLException e){
```

no me lo permite, como se puede ver en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me dice que capturando a `SQLException` ya capturo cualquier `PSQLException`

Y si intento colocarla en un `catch` aparte:

```
    } catch(PSQLException e){
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tampoco me deja. Dice que la excepción ya está siendo capturada.

### Excepción provocada

Con el código así:

```
    try 
    {  

         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         Connection cnx = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, userName, userPassword);

        //...


    } catch(ClassNotFoundException  | SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Error en JDBC: "+e.getMessage());            

    }
```

Genero una excepción a propósito, y al corre el código, tengo esto en el output:

> Error en JDBC: FATAL: password authentication failed for user
>   "postgres"

**Nótese además** que `ClassNotFoundException` no admite el uso de `getErrorCode()`.

<s>**Nota:** Si sigue sin capturar la excepción, puede que se esté generando a otro nivel, y por eso se escape. En ese caso, puedes hacer una prueba cambiando en el `catch` `PSQLException`  por `Exception` a ver qué pasa. Si eso ocurre, por favor indica qué driver de postgresql tienes y cómo lo tienes instalado.</s>

Comment: despues de Java 7 deberia de funcionar tambien mostrando el error `System.out.println(ex.getErrorCode());`?

Comment: Eso que dices ya lo he probado, he usado Exception y no funciona, como driver tengo el postgresql-42.1.4.jar, añadido al proyecto en Eclipse como Referenced Libraries.

Comment: No funciona generalizando al Exception, entra en el catch, realiza el código, pero también aparece en consola de interrupción que no quiero que aparezca.

Comment: @Runsert es normal que aparezca en consola si invocas `System.out.print...` o si usas `PrintStackTrace()`. La idea de capturar las excepciones es que no haya un crash en la aplicación y se cierre. A partir de ahí tú decides si poner un mensaje en alguna parte de la pantalla por ejemplo o no.

Comment: Ya, el problema que tengo es que quiero que no aparezca en consola el mensaje en letras rojas que aparece al fallar la conexión, porque al hacer el catch el programa no crashea pero sigue apareciendo las letras rojas de error.

Comment: @Runsert en mi prueba, el mensaje de las letras rojas aparece únicamente al usar `e.PrintStackTrace()`, en cambio, si quito eso y pongo un `System.out.println`, me imprime mi mensaje de error en pantalla y nada más. Porque `PrintStackTrace` imprime una traza de la pila, indicando exactamente dónde está el error.

Comment: puedes poner tu codigo completo @A. Cedano? a mi me aparecen las letras rojas usando:
 try {
   Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( url, usuario, password);
   }catch(Exception ex){
    
   System.out.println(ex);
   }       
Usando Eclipse, me aparecen el error en letras rojas y luego el error del system.out.println..

Comment: @Runsert agregué una última parte a la respuesta titulada **Excepción provocada**.

Comment: Gracias pero no funciona, ¿has probado a realizar la conexión fallida a a PostgreSql en el try para reproducir el error tal como me aparece a mi?

Comment: @Runsert , yo conecto desde otra parte, pero lo he puesto en el `try` como sugieres, he probado y me funciona. Edita la pregunta poniendo cómo tienes el código a ver si hay algo extraño en él.

Comment: El codigo completo lo tienes arriba del todo desde el principio.